# Google Chart implementation on software system

Tags: google-visualization

does google charts have a library for software development that does not require internet connection during our implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so.

The advantage - for Google - is that the software stays on their servers *where users can't inspect it and reverse engineer it*.

And it fits in with Google's aim of making us use *Cloud Computing*.

Comment: if that wouldn't be possible, considering an alternative for a JAVA implementation. would JChart be a good choice in considering graphical data like bar graphs and pie charts?

Comment: I don't know about JChart - my requirements were very different (not bar charts and pie charts)